# Simple local extension model extend problem

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I wan't to extend local extension model with this existing config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Smartwave_All>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Smartwave_All>
    </modules>      
    <global>
        ...
        <models>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <layout>Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout</layout>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
            <all>
                <class>Smartwave_All_Model</class>
            </all>
        </models>
        ...
    </global>
</config>
```

This is the file which I wan't to extend with my public function (app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php):

```
<?php 
class Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout extends Mage_Core_Model_Layout
{ ...
```

Ok, now here are my extension files(app/etc/modules/SampleCompany_Test.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SampleCompany_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Smartwave_All/>
            </depends>
        </SampleCompany_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And my config.xml (app/code/local/SampleCompany/Test/etc/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SampleCompany_Test>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </SampleCompany_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <smartwave_all>
                <rewrite>
                    <core_layout>SampleCompany_Test_Model_Layout</core_layout>
                </rewrite>
            </smartwave_all>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And of course my Layout.php (app/code/local/SampleCompany/Test/Model/Layout.php):

```
class SampleCompany_Test_Model_Layout extends Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout
{
    public function myNewFunction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I can't get this to work. Main problem is because Smartwave All is rewriting Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php core file and it is in conflict with my other extension which do the same (rewrites Layout.php). Now I wan't to extend Smartwave All instead of core Layout.php.

Thanks for any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're declaring your Smartwave_All models like this:

```
<all>
     <class>Smartwave_All_Model</class>
</all>
```

But you're doing the rewrite like this:

```
<smartwave_all>
   <rewrite>
        <core_layout>SampleCompany_Test_Model_Layout</core_layout>
   </rewrite>
</smartwave_all>
```

Where it should be:

```
<all>
   <rewrite>
        <core_layout>SampleCompany_Test_Model_Layout</core_layout>
   </rewrite>
</all>
```

Or the other way around you can change your models declaration like this:

```
<smartware_all>
     <class>Smartwave_All_Model</class>
</smartware_all>
```